# Best reading width for reading content?

Tags: text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ideal column width for paragraphs online](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3618/ideal-column-width-for-paragraphs-online)

What are the most conventional type of width to read content, especially long content? Is there any studies ?

For example [stackexchange](http://stackexchange.com) & [newyorktimes](https://www.nytimes.com) only use about 60-70% of their content box, rather than 100%... Is this just to be able to provide a sidebar with links to help users keep interacting with the site? Or for reading usability?